# Using several IDEs .. Virtual machine or no VM

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vmware-workstation, development

I'm using a bunch of debuggers, IDEs. They install a huge load of software on the PC and some  of them also runs as service (I could write a batch file for this though). When I try to uninstall them, it is really hard to remove one.

Since I have a license for VMWare Workstation , I thought installing XP into a guest and using the stuff there. However, I have a question. VMWare runs some services (which I couldn't stop since it kills my networking if I do).

Is runing vmware that resource hungry? (Not when running the guest, but when it actually just stays in the background, runs as a proccess).

By the way I use Win7 x64, and VMWare 7.1 workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got enough RAM so the VM isn't starved of memory (I'd got for 3-4GB for the VM), that is a pretty good way of running a development environment, especially if you want/need to debug and run you software under several versions of Windows.

Comment: hmm ok you conviced me. But I'll wait if someone got actual experience (No offense, thanks for the answer :))

Comment: @Shiki - I guess I should have pointed out that I tend to run a bunch of development environments (not only Windows) that way :).

Comment: Well..sorry. :))